# SharePoint/MOSS "Web/" vs "Web/Pages" vs "Pages/page.aspx"

Tags: security, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have two SharePoint/MOSS installations using the same Solution. On one installation, surfing to the following URLs as an anonymous user give the following results:

```
http://site/Web/                   => redirect to /site/Web/Pages/welcome.aspx
http://site/Web/Pages              => redirect to /site/Web/Pages/welcome.aspx
http://site/Web/Pages/             => redirect to /site/Web/Pages/welcome.aspx
http://site/Web/Pages/welcome.aspx => welcome.aspx
```

However, on another installation, the results are thus:

```
http://site/Web/                   => redirect to /site/Web/Pages/welcome.aspx
http://site/Web/Pages              => Access denied
http://site/Web/Pages/             => Access denied
http://site/Web/Pages/welcome.aspx => welcome.aspx
```

When getting Access denied, and logging on, the redirect is performed as usual.

The two installations have slight differences regarding Farm setup and how sites are Extended, but nothing that is obviously relevant to the problem. Both installations have anonymous access setup so the above should work.

When the Access denied occurs, the SharePoint trace log file in Verbose mode shows the following:

- Looking up context  site http://site/pages in the farm abcd235f139b-8396-4255-bc31-bc22de0a8337
- Looking up the additional information about the typical site http://site/pages.
- Site lookup is replacing http://site/pages with the alternate access url http://site.
- Looking up typical site http://site/pages in web application SPWebApplication Name=abcd Parent=SPWebService.
  **PermissionMask check failed. asking for 0x00001000, have 0x00030041**

I've **found this problem in the wild**. Compare these two:

```
http://www.kahrs.com/de/Consumer/AboutKahrs/Pages => redirect to welcome page
http://www.moviatrafik.dk/Pages                   => Access denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me warn you that, first, I know very little (almost nothing) about Sharepoint.

That said, it sounds like a permission issue.  There are two pages I've found that might explain some of this:

- http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sprights.aspx
- http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx

Here are the permissions it has:

- ViewListItems     -- View items in lists, documents in document libraries, and view Web discussion comments.
- EditListItems     -- Edit items in lists, edit documents in document libraries, edit Web discussion comments in documents, and customize Web Part Pages in document libraries.
- ViewPages -- View pages in a Web site.
- Open -- Allow users to open a Web site, list, or folder to access items inside that container

From those pages, the right it wants is:

- ViewFormPages     -- View forms, views, and application pages, and enumerate lists.

The first thing I would check is what the permission on those specific paths/pages/whatever are, and see if something is amiss.

I suppose it could also be what is done when permission is NOT allowed.  Perhaps the other site has "if you're not able to touch these pages, then you are redirected " or specific redirects for all of those paths to the welcome page.

Comment: Interesting. But I think what it has and what it needs are reversed (i.e. it has only 11-00000000-01000001, but needs 10000-00000000).

Comment: You are right -- I'll edit the proposed hint-like answer.

Comment: Any luck on this one?

Comment: Yes and no. It seems the problem is related to where the traffic is coming from - internally from the same machine or externally from another machine. It also seems to be related to whether anonymous access is enabled for the entire web site. So I have everything working, but it's brought me no closer to actually understanding why this is a problem and why it works differently on different setups. I'll try and find out more before the bounty ends.

Comment: It's very hard when I don't quite understand how sharepoint works.  :)

My guess is that traffic sources are classified in terms of internal and external.  That's a very microsoft concept.  Then there's authenticated vs anonymous.  I'd look at these settings between the two installations and see what flags might be different affecting those areas.